# How to implement switching font families by button click in Next 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to switch font families on the button click. And I need to apply this choosen font in layout.tsx, so it would affect all the other children components.

I tried to use nookies and cookies-next, but it didnt help me. So the question is: how to implement switching fonts on click & getting access to cookies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.